# DocuSign : send document to two signers , complete whenever one of them signs

Tags: docusignapi

using the DocuSign API is it possible to build a workflow where we send one document to two (or more) signers in such a way that the document envelope gets marked as "complete" as soon as one of the signers signs...e.g., we send a document to persons A and B, as soon as person A signs then DocuSign marks the envelope as complete and B no longer has to sign.
Cheers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocuSign behavior is such that each and every existing "signer" for an Envelope must access the Envelope and "confirm signing" before the Envelope can move to a status of "Completed".  However, it IS possible to implement the workflow you describe -- with some coding on your part.

For this example, let's assume you create an Envelope with 3 recipients, each of type **signer**.  As soon as any one of the 3 recipients completes/submits the Envelope, you want the Envelope to be considered Complete.  You could achieve this by doing the following:

- Implement **[DocuSign Connect](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/connect)** either at the account level OR at the Envelope level (by setting **eventNotification** properties in the API request that creates/sends the Envelope) -- such that DocuSign Connect will send the "listener" endpoint you specify an HTTP POST message (in XML format) whenever a "Recipient Signed/Completed" event occurs for an Envelope.
- Build/code your "listener" application to parse the XML messages it receives from DocuSign Connect, and if/when a message indicates that a recipient signed an Envelope, code your "listener" application such that it makes an API call to DocuSign to Delete each remaining **signer** recipient for the specified Envelope. In the example of an Envelope that contains 3 signers -- signer A, B, and C -- this would mean deleting signers A and C if the Envelope's been signed by signer B.

As soon as an Envelope no longer contains any recipients that must receive/acknowledge/complete the Envelope, the Envelope's status will automatically advance to "Completed".  By implementing the procedure I've outlined above, you're essentially *forcing* an Envelope to complete by removing/deleting all incomplete recipients by using the API, as soon as DocuSign Connect notifies you that a recipient has signed.  [Do note, however, that when you remove/delete a recipient from an Envelope, that recipient loses the ability to access the Envelope from that point forward.]